# Disable/hide/remove Sign In Adobe Acrobat Pro DC version 2019

Tags: windows-10, adobe-reader-dc

[image]

I know in previous version there was a registry key you could edit for this, but I cant find it for this version, please help. thank you

Comment: Adobe tracks its licenses. Sign in once, and then be done with it.

Comment: Isn't Adobe Acrobat Pro DC only available through a subscription?  The last time i purchased Adobe Acrobat Pro my only option for a perpetual license was Adobe Acrobat Pro 2019.